# Bootstrap 3 GRID order

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

How to change columns order on window resize in bootstrap 3 grid?
Here an image what i try to get:

[Change bootstrap order on window resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RJhw.png)

PROBLEM SOLVED!
CODE:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-xs-6">Box1
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-push-8 col-md-6 col-xs-6">Box2
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-pull-2 col-md-12 col-xs-12">Box3
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried so far. Have you read the [many other questions on column ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bootstrap+column+order)?

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple classes for different window size. **use this code in your local html file**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pavan, i asked about change order of bootstrap grid elements. Problem solved by adding col-md-pull and col-md-push classes.